# Finding values of C that validate discrete probability density functions

Tags: probability

I want to state first that this is a homework problem that I've been working on for a week but I just can't seem to crack it.

I have to "find a value of c such that f(x) becomes a valid probability density function, where f(x)=12c^x, and x=2,3,4...

Where I'm getting tripped up is the summation, as opposed to the integration you do on continuous pdfs, and more specifically the fact that it is an infinite series, so I'm not sure how to go about finding C.

Thanks so much for any help or hints about how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinite Geometric series. $a + ar + ar^2 + ar^3 +...+ar^n$ = $\frac{a}{1-r}$

http://www.mathwords.com/i/infinite_geometric_series.htm

use this and set the sum of the series equal to 1, then solve for c. note this series starts at 0, not 2.